# SPSS Python get filename of active dataset

Tags: python, filenames, spss

In SPSS, using Python program, is there a way to get the filename of the Active Dataset ? I am not talking about the Dataset Name; I need the filename.

```
SPSS_Path=os.path.dirname(SpssClient.GetActiveDataDoc().GetDocumentPath())
```

gets the path, and I am looking for something similar for the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this was the spssaux module, which is installed with Python Essentials in SPSS 23 (may not be in older versions, but I can't test it). Credits to [this old post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014523026#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014523028) on IBM forum.

```
begin program.
import spss,spssaux

#this gets the whole path+filename+fileextension into a string:
Data_Info=str(spssaux.GetDatasetInfo())

#find the position of the last "/" in the above string, to determine the path
Slash_Pos=Data_Info.rfind("/")

#find the position of the last ".", to determine file extension
Ext_Pos=Data_Info.rfind(".")

#get Active File name
SPSS_Name = Data_Info[Slash_Pos+1:Ext_Pos]

#get Active File Path
SPSS_Path=Data_Info[:Slash_Pos+1]

print (SPSS_Name, SPSS_Path)
end program.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that function has been available for a long time.  Note that the active dataset does not always have a file name.